# How to change two variable status in one if statement? (python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I'd like to change two variable's values by one 'if' statement. And system said I have unexpected indent error. My code is on below. What's my problem here? (I'm using powershell under windows xp, python version:2.7)

```
z = 1
zz = 11
def x():
    global z,zz
    print 'xxxx'
    y = input()
    if y == yes:
    z = 0 
    zz = 0
    print 'bla bla bla'

x()
print z
print zz
```

Comment: @Ken, I realized it soon after I posted it. Thanks

Comment: `z = 0` is not indented underneath the `if`. move it in four spaces to be aligned with `zz = 0`

Comment: Are you looking for `z, zz = 0, 0`?

Comment: @dim, I indented in my own code, but it seems I've made some mistakes when putting on stackoverflow with it's automatic coding detection function. Whuuf, My reputation hurts!

Comment: I think you can delete the question and get the reputation back... (thats my understanding of how it works).

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, Thank you. That's exact what I need. But how should I do "if y == yes: z +=1, zz += 1"?

Comment: @Mario, see my edited answer for a functioning example

Comment: either use semicolons (ugh!) or use `z, zz = z+1, zz+1`

Comment: @Mario Please leave the original question the way it is. Don't edit to change it to something else.

Comment: @alKid, OK, next time I'll notice it more. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to read your error:

```
  File "indenttest.py", line 8                <- stacktrace
    z = 0                                     <- line of code
    ^                                         <- indicates which char on above line
IndentationError: expected an indented block  <- error
```

The stacktrace shows which functions were called on the way to your error, in this case none were called because the interpreter hit a syntax error while parsing your file, so it just shows you that the error was in your file on line 8.

The line of code shows which line in your source had the error. The `^` character below that points to the position on that line.

Now the error says `IndentationError` - if you look that up you might find this page http://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/indentation.html which explains how indentation in python works.

**EDIT**

Given your new code, the problem lies with your use of `input()` - you should be using `raw_input()` for reading text from the user. You also need to put your `yes` literal in string quotes `"yes"` or `'yes'`. Here's a functioning version of your code:

```
z = 1
zz = 11
def x():
    global z,zz
    print 'xxxx'
    y = raw_input('type something:')
    if y == 'yes':
        z = 0 
        zz = 0
        print 'bla bla bla'

x()
print z
print zz
```

When you run that, you get:

```
$python indenttest.py 
xxxx
type something:yes
bla bla bla
0
0

$ python indenttest.py 
xxxx
type something:no
1
11
```

Comment: Hi, I tried on my shell, still error occurs. Is it because there may be some limit on my computer? I was using the computer of my company.

Comment: I rerun it, now it works! thank you! But I may need to delete my question to get my reputation back. Would you mind it? if you are mind about your answer, I'll keep this question open.

Comment: I don't mind if you want to delete it

Comment: It can't be deleted now, because you've answered it. I've renewed my question with the more proximate prototype of my code. It shows indent error, too. Without input(), what's wrong here?

Comment: !!!! my new code is executable after I paste it from StackOverFlow. I guess maybe my computer's OS has some kind of problem.!!

Comment: @Mario, make sure you're not using `tab`s for indenting - the interpreter treats spaces and tabs differently even though they might look the same in the editor. It's best to use 4 spaces everywhere with Python.

Comment: I don't know. I was using notepad and txt in company. It sucks. At home I have Ubuntu, I use vim and gedit and never met such problems.

Comment: Oh my god, you are my santo. When I debug my program at home. I found it's exactly caused by the tab indenting made by notepad. Oh, Jesus, thank you for enlightened me. Thank you indeed.

Comment: Oh, I've heard this notorious tab indenting thing, I just never thought it would happened on me. Now I don't feel pity for my reputation any more. I met you here. It's my fortune.